# How to fetch current browser version dynamically in multiple cucumber html reporter

Tags: cucumber, cypress

I am using multiple cucumber html reported in my cypress tests. I have a file called cucumber-html-report.js, which contains below metadata.

```
metadata: {
    browser: {
        name: 'chrome',
        version: '100'
        
    },
    device: os.platform(),
    platform: {
        name: 'Windows',
        version: os.release()
    }
```

Here the browser version is static which is '100' in this case. I want this to be dynamic i.e. it should fetch current chrome version and display in reports (like it does for OS)

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch browser version by `Cypress.browser.version` keyword
for example - `const currentBrowserVersion = Cypress.browser.version;` 
 and after put the data in the report

Comment: I tried above solution like this.

`const currentBrowserVersion = Cypress.browser.version;
metadata: {
        browser: {
           name: 'chrome',
           version: currentBrowserVersion          
        },`



But this does not seems to work . It throws 'Cypress is not defined' error

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to inspect your json file you got after the test ran. In my case I inspect it and found the info related to browser data and OS and used in `cucumber-html-report.js`. Here is the code snippet for you maybe it will be different in your json but it should be something like that.

```
 metadata: {
          browser: {
            name: browserMap(runInfos.browserName),
            version: runInfos.browserVersion
          },
          device: 'Test Device',
          platform: {
            name: osMap(runInfos.osName)
          }
```

and the `browserMap ()` look like this:

```
let browserMap = browser => {
  if (browser.startsWith('electron') || browser.startsWith('chrome')) {
    return 'chrome'
  } else if (browser.startsWith('firefox')) {
    return 'firefox'
  } else if (browser.startsWith('safari')) {
    return 'safari'
  } else if (browser.startsWith('internet explorer')) {
    return 'internet explorer'
  } else {
    return 'edge'
  }
}
```

and `runInfo` will look like this

```
 let runInfos = JSON.parse(data)
```

Hope it will help you